# Did Nolan deliberately do the Joker fall scene in reverse to Burton's version?

Tags: the-dark-knight, batman-1989

In The Dark Knight, Batman caused the Joker to fall from a building but he saved him from falling in the end.

[image]

But in Tim Burton's Batman, Batman was the one solely responsible for Joker's fall.

[image]

Both scenes have some parallels as initially Batman caused the fall which even looked similar but in Nolan's version (except the body position was reversed), he saved him. So why did Nolan make this change of Joker's fate in his film? Even when in the film he killed Two-Face later the same way?

Comment: Interesting question (edited some stuff). Also note that the grapple gun plays a key part in both (and it hits the joker's leg in both scenes, though to a reverse effect).

Comment: [BTW: *"in Tim Burton's Batman, Batman was the one solely responsible for Joker's fall"* Well, not *really*... He secured him to a gargoyle. If he'd just let go of that chopper, he might've lived. Eventually, the Joker kinda killed himself.]

Comment: @Walt But he didn't even tried to save him but Nolan's batman did saved him

Comment: How could he? He was barely hanging on. That's presumably the best he could've done.

Comment: @Walt but he is batman if he can stop him from reaching helicopter then why not try to stop him from falling, it's all depend on script

Comment: Sure, I'm just saying that Batman's not *solely* responsible... He did give the Joker a choice, and was rather incapacitated. Batman didn't *exactly* kill him, but he couldn't (or wouldn't) save him either. A bit like in *Begins*.

Comment: I don't have a source for this, so I'll just leave it as a comment, I think it does a few things: teases viewers by subverting the outcome (like SF stated in their answer), they wanted to keep things open for Joker to return in a sequel, and because I do think it make's Nolan's version more controversial, because he did initiate the fall more directly than Burton's Batman, but he also then saves him, showing that he isn't as bad, as he could be, squaring him nicely into the anti-hero category.

Comment: I'm unsure if Nolan ever addressed this question. However, it was a complete reversal all the way through. In Burton's, Batman struggles greatly with the Joker's henchmen, then physically demolishes the Joker in a one-on-one fight that ends with the Joker falling to his death. In The Dark Knight, Batman handily defeats the Joker's henchmen, only to be overpowered by the Joker and eventually save the Joker from certain death.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, as it does subvert the viewers expectations as to the outcome of that final showdown, but remember - at the time the scene was conceived and photographed no body could foresee the upcoming tragedy involving Ledger and it is possible that the character was kept alive for possible future use in the sequel.